# Accessing .epub files using Google Drive API v3

Tags: google-drive-api, epub

I am having some trouble working with the Google Drive API v3.  I am trying to make an e-reader application and am using Google Drive as the storage solution for the epub files.

My trouble comes when I try to access the .epub file for display in my application.  I am using the Futurepress epub.js library (https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/) for display and manipulation of the files.

I so far have been unsuccessful in being able to access an epub file and obtain any sort of url from Google Drive required to display the epub file in my app.  Is there any way for me to obtain a url from Google Drive that will allow me to access the file for use in the epub.js library I am using in my application?  I have looked at "files.get" in the references, but it only seems like I can download the epub file from drive to another server rather than accessing it in the browser directly from Drive.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Talk to the author of the FF addon [EPUBReader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/epubreader/?src=ssZ). He might be able to tell you if this is possible or not. Also tried the [Mobileread Forum](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/). They might know if this is possible, or who to send you to.

Comment: Awesome.  I will follow up with those and report my findings here.  Thanks  for the advice!